# Failing to download image and store as bitmap on android

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-file

I am trying to download an image from the internet and save it to my internal storage to be used elsewhere in my app. However the image that is received fails to compress and save. `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);` throws a nullpointer. Any help is appreciated.

```
    private String SaveImage(String imageURL) {


        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            // Download Image from URL
            URL testUrl = new URL(imageURL);
            URLConnection urlConnection = testUrl.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

            Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - 300) >= Math.abs(options.outWidth - 300);

            if(options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 200*200*2){
                // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 that'll get it <= desired dimensions
                double sampleSize = scaleByHeight
                        ? options.outHeight / 300
                        : options.outWidth / 300;
                options.inSampleSize =
                        (int)Math.pow(2d, Math.floor(
                                Math.log(sampleSize)/Math.log(2d)));
            }

            // Do the actual decoding
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            is.close();
            is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
            is.close();

            String root = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 100000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-" + n + ".png";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out); //here
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            return getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString() + "/saved_images/" + "Image-" + n + ".png";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If bitmap== null then do not use it for bitmap.compress().

Comment: Further you should not use an intermediate bitmap at all. Just make a loop where you read some bytes from the input stream and then write them to your file output stream.

Comment: Which one is null? `bitmap` or `outputstream`?

Comment: the bitmap is null. I guess it didnt download properly